# Formula for simulating radioactive decay for a large number of isotopes

Tags: algorithms, stochastic-processes, simulation

Currently I'm working on a project where I need to simulate the decay of a number of isotopes after each second.

One way to do so is each second do a uniform random roll for each particle, and if it is smaller than the decay constant, then count it as a decay.

Although this model is accurate it is very inefficient for large numbers of particles.

My second approach was to use a binomial distribution to model the decay. This works fine when the number of particles is sufficiently large, but fails when the probability of a decay is small.

For instance lets take Tritium, with a half life of $3.88524\times10^{8}$ seconds. If we have $2,000,000$ particles of Tritium, we expect 1 decay about every 5 minutes. By running the first simulation, indeed this is the case; however for the second one a decay never happens (for as long as I ran the experiment).

Any advice on how to better model this phenomenon?

EDIT: here is the first code that simulates correctly

```
production = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < number; i++){
    rand = Math.random();
    if(rand <  decay_constant){
        production++;
    }
}
```

Here is the code that simulates incorrectly

```
// p is the decay constant
var p = Math.log(2) / half_life;
var q = 1-p;
var mean = number*p;
var variance = number*p*q;
var std = Math.sqrt(variance);          
prod = Math.round(numberGenerator.nextGaussian()*std+mean);
```

Comment: There must be something wrong with your second simulation, then. Perhaps if you told what you're doing there someone might be able to see _what_ is wrong with it. As it is, you're essentially just saying _"I wrote a program with a bug in it that I'm not showing you; please telepathically figure out where the bug in the program you can't see is"._

Comment: @HenningMakholm the second simulation is just a binomial distribution draw. I wrote on this forum and not on a programming one because I'm quite confident what is wrong is the math,not the code. I have editted the question to include both snippets of code.

Comment: Inter-decay time is exponentially distributed: $T\sim \exp(\lambda)$ where $\lambda$ is your decay rate (inverse of the average time between decays). Ideally, you would update (reduce) your $\lambda$ after each decay, but since the number of particles is so large, you don't need to do it for quite a few decays. You can generate such a $T$  by $T=-\lambda\log U$ for standard uniform $U$.

Comment: More precisely the time between $i$th and $i+1$st decay is $T_i\sim \exp(\lambda'(N-i))$ where $\lambda'$ is decay rate of a single particle and $N$ is the number of particles.

Comment: Your incorrect code appears to use a normal distribution rather than the binomial one you said you were using. Some binomial distributions can be _approximated_ as normal distributions, but that does not hold for binomial distributions that skew heavily towards $0$, such as your case.

Comment: With numbers in the range you describe, a Poisson distribution with $\lambda=np$ would be a much better approximation to the binomial one.

Comment: @HenningMakholm thanks, that is what I was looking for. EDIT: any rule of thumb about when to use Poisson and when normal?

Comment: @angar You use Poisson whenever $p'\ll 1$ and binomial whenever $np'\gg 1$ where $p'=\min\{p,1-p\}$. If both conditions are satisfied, you can use either one. As a rule of thumb $\ll, \gg$ is at least one order of magnitude (factor of $10$ difference at least).

Comment: @angarg12: For specific examples, see my Answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some exact probability computations comparing Poisson,
binomial, and normal distributions. I believe the Poisson
distribution is best as long as the period of time considered
is several orders of magnitude less than the half life. (For longer
periods of time adjustments of the kind suggested in the
Comment by @A.S. are helpful.)

**Poisson model for one minute with binomial approximation.** The number of decays $X$ observed in one minute should average $\lambda = 1/5.$ So we use $X \sim Pois(\lambda = 1/5).$ Because the
number of particles is $n = 2 \times 10^6$ a binomial distribution
with $p = \lambda/n = 10^{-7}$ has the same mean. For these parameters the 
fit is quite good. The following R code makes a table of the
respective probabilities for $x = 0, 1, 2, 3$ and the left
panel of the figure at the end (Poisson bars, binomial open circles).

Roughly speaking, a sufficient condition for a reasonable fit between binomial and Poisson is that $n$ be very large, $p$ very small, and $\lambda = np$ of moderate size.
However, this Poisson distribution is
so severely skewed that it does not make sense to try a normal
approximation.

```
 # ONE MINUTE
 x = 0:3;  lam = 1/5;  n = 2*10^6;  p = lam/n
 pdf.pois = dpois(x, lam);  pdf.bino = dbinom(x, n, p)
 cbind(x, pdf.pois, pdf.bino)
 ##     x    pdf.pois    pdf.bino
 ##     0 0.818730753 0.818730745
 ##     1 0.163746151 0.163746165
 ##     2 0.016374615 0.016374610
 ##     3 0.001091641 0.001091640

 par(mfrow = c(1,2))  # permits two panels per figure
 plot(x, pdf.pois, type="h", lwd=2, ylab="PDF", main="POIS(.2) With BINO Aprx")
 points(x, pdf.bino, col="blue")
 abline(h=0, col="green2")
```

**Poisson model for one hour with binomial and normal approximations.** The number of decays $X$ in one hour has a mean 60 times as large,
so we use $X \sim Pois(\lambda = 12).$ The corresponding binomial
has the same $n$ as above and $p = \lambda/n = 6 \times 10^{-6},\,$ so that
the means match.

As $\lambda$ increases, Poisson distributions
become less skewed and a normal approximation becomes feasible.
You can see, by the plot in the right hand panel below, that 
$\lambda = 12$ is not yet quite large enough for a really good
approximation. The appropriate normal approximation is $Norm(\mu = \lambda,\, \sigma =\sqrt{\lambda}).$ The additional R code below finishes the plot.

```
 # ONE HOUR   
 x=0:30;  lam=12;  m=2*10^6;  p = lam/n
 pdf.pois = dpois(x, lam);  pdf.bino = dbinom(x, n, p)
 plot(x, pdf.pois, type="h", lwd=2, ylab="PDF",main="POIS(12) W/ BINO & NORM Aprx")
 points(x, pdf.bino, col="blue")
 curve(dnorm(x, lam, sqrt(lam)), col="maroon", add=T) 
 abline(h=0, col="green2")
 par(mfrow = c(1,1))  # returns to default single-panel plots
```

[image]

As an example: for the probability of 10 or fewer events in an hour,
the Poisson and binomial distributions both give 0.3472, and the normal approximation
0.3325 (all rounded to four places).

```
 ppois(10, 12);  pbinom(10, 2*10^6, 6*10^-6);  pnorm(10.5, 12, sqrt(12))  
 ## 0.3472294
 ## 0.3472288
 ## 0.3325028
```

---

Note: I hope the R code is sufficiently transparent that you can
follow it as much as you need to, and perhaps make minor
modifications. R software is available free of
charge and with easy installation at `www.R-project.org`. There are Windows, Mac, and UNIX versions. I have used only the 'base' of R
(no libraries) and put #-symbols to keep answers and comments
from interfering with running the code as shown.